# Не могу вставить лейбл с временем в виджет

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qtimer

У меня есть код, в котором есть виджет в левой стороне основного окна, и я захотел вставить время в самый низ этого виджета, однако ничего не вышло и я не понимаю почему. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот пример кода с временем:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))

        
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        #вроде можно удалить
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        #не совсем понял зачем
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 20))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"


"border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"

"}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"


"border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"

"}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        #создаем виджет
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('солнце.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"

"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
    
"}")    
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(showTime)
        timer.start(1000)


        font1 = QFont('Arial', 8, QFont.Bold)
        #попытка указать время внутри левого фрейма
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel(showTime, self.frame_top_menus)
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        #функция для показа времени
        def showTime(self):
            current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
            label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
            self.timewidget.setText(label_time)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        #указываем заметки в левом фрейме
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800,535))

        self.stackedWidget.setStyleSheet('QStackedWidget{\n'
            'border: 0px solid;')
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        #1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница1", self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #ba135d;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(0)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
  
        
    # функция с анимацией выдвижения виджета путем наведения курсора
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот пример кода без времени:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *




class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")        
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
      
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))


        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)

        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 20))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"

"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"

"}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)

        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"

"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"

"}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('солнце.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"

"}")
        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
      
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800,535))

        self.stackedWidget.setStyleSheet('QStackedWidget{\n'
            'border: 0px solid;')
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница1", self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #ba135d;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("PAGE 3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(0)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        # PAGE 1
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        # PAGE 2
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        # PAGE 3
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        
    # функция с анимацией выдвижения виджета путем наведения курсора
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте метод `showTime(self)` - методом класса и вставьте `timewidget` в нужный layout - `self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)`

Я отметил строки, которые надо изменить. Спросите если что-то не понятно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        #вроде можно удалить
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        #не совсем понял зачем
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 20))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        #создаем виджет
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('lena.jpg'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")    

        timer = QTimer(self)
#        timer.timeout.connect(showTime)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)                                   # +++
        timer.start(1000)


        font1 = QFont('Arial', 8, QFont.Bold)
        
# попытка указать время внутри левого фрейма
#        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel(showTime, self.frame_top_menus)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()                                   # +++
        
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        '''
        #функция для показа времени
        def showTime(self):
            current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
            label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
            self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
        '''

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        #указываем заметки в левом фрейме
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800,535))

        self.stackedWidget.setStyleSheet('QStackedWidget{\n'
            'border: 0px solid;')
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        #1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница1", self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #ba135d;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(0)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)    # +++

# +++ функция для показа времени                                                      # +++
    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
        
    # функция с анимацией выдвижения виджета путем наведения курсора
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        # ...      
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как добавить еще одну кнопку? Я попробовал добавить еще 1 кнопку, все работает, только сама кнопка находится в самом верху левого виджета и я не понимаю как ее передвинуть под третью кнопку, можете помочь?

Comment: @ivapop если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приведите ваш код, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: хорошо, щас выложу